# VLC stops recording all of a sudden

Tags: vlc-media-player

I have a task scheduled in my Windows 7 Task Scheduler. It runs this command:

```
"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\VLC.exe" "rtmp://streamhost.com/somestream" :demux=dump :demuxdump-file="C:\Users\acer\Desktop\FileName.flv" --run-time 3900 vlc://quit
```

While it had been doing the job just fine since weeks, off late, it stops recording after 15-20 mins. While the VLC interface does remains as it would while recording a stream, but it doesn't receive any packets. The network packet/byte counter stops moving to suggest that it isn't recording anything.

Anyone faced this situation before?? Any suggestions??

Comment: @DavidPostill The two questions have different motive. This question intends to troubleshoot the issue with VLC abruptly stopping its recording. The other question, on the other hand, is aimed at finding a reliable alternative to Windows' native Task Scheduler software to solve the scheduling aspect.

Comment: @DavidPostill It's basically one big problem with various sub-problems. I do get the dilemna. The second para in the other post seems to be bringing this problem to that post too. I've suitably amended it. Kindly unlock this question so that people can help me with this. :)

Comment: @DavidPostill could you please unmark this as a duplicate question?

Comment: <shrug> Done. I don't think it will help you any answers though ...

Comment: @DavidPostill Umm...Why do you think so??

Comment: Well you've had no comments (apart from me) or answers to either question in 4 days ... and I can't answer either of your questions ...

Comment: That's true... Could you suggest a place where I could find help other that SuperUser?

Comment: Sorry, no idea :/